# isselected on second listview same as on the first

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, datatemplate, relativesource

I got a grid with 2 listviews in it. The listviews are the same(Only itemsource is different for other items ofc) the datatemplate = Stackpanel that has 1 Label and an other grid. Now I want the grid (inside the stackpanel that is inside the Datatemplate) ONLY to be visible if the item is selected(The Label). I tried it with this code(that I put in the datatemplate of the Listview :

```
<StackPanel>
<Label content={binding blabla} />
<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Mode=OneWay,  Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" >
...random labels etc...
</Gird>
</StackPanel>
```

This works! HOWEVER if I select an item in the 2nd listview (And only the 2nd) then the first one also shows that grid(on the same "item level").(So for example on the 2nd listview I select the 3th item(the label), then the Grid is show on the 3th item of the 2nd listview but the 3th item grid is show on the first listview!!!!)

I Think this has to do with the relative source thing, but I coudn t find an answer.
Hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a `ListBox` doesn't have focus, doesn't mean an item gets unselected, and I suspect you have the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` bound to the same property in both `ListViews` which is making the `ListViewItem.IsSelected` synchronized between the two ListViews

I'd suggest making your Grid's Visibility condition be based on 2 properties instead of 1: the `ListViewItem.IsSelected` is true, AND if the `ListViewItem.IsKeyboardFocusWithin` is set to True.

Here's an example using a `DataTrigger`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}" x:Key="GridStyle">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Value="True" Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}" />
                <Condition Value="True" Binding="{Binding Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Actually in retrospect, I think `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` will set the items as selected, so perhaps you only need to use `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` instead of `IsSelected`

Comment: Will try this once I come home. Think you ll be my hero again Rachel n1! :D

Comment: oke it works, beside, now If I Click on an item of an listview the other listview item that was open(Grid was visible) now closes. Is there a way to fix this perhaps ?

Comment: @Maximc If you want to maintain the visible `Grid` for the selected item, I would use `IsSelected` instead of `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`, and make sure you bind the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` of your ListViews to two different values. It sounds like they're bound to the same value, so the selection is synchronized.